# Checking a task in a react app also checks the one below it

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a simple to do list app in React. I'm encountering a problem where checking an item also checks the one below it in the list:

[image]

Even with a delay between checking the item & filtering the list:

[image]

Any ideas what could be causing this?

https://jsfiddle.net/yn03bx7w/

```
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
} = React;

const {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardActionArea,
  CardContent,
  Checkbox,
  ThemeProvider,
  Typography,
} = MaterialUI;

function Task(props) {
    return (
      <Card sx={{p: 1, m: 1, ...props.additionalStyles}}>
        <CardActionArea>
          <CardContent style={{padding: 2}}>
            <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Checkbox onChange={props.onChecked}/>
              <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                <Typography variant='body1' component='div' fontFamily='Segoe UI'>
                {props.title}
                </Typography>
              </div>
            </div>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    );
}

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
      setTasks([
        {
          title: "Task 1",
          color: "red",
        },
        {
          title: "Task 2",
        },
        {
          title: "Task 3",
          color: "blue",
        },
      ]);
  }, []);

  const completeTask = (task) => {
      task.isChecked = true;
      setTasks(tasks.filter(t => !t.isChecked));
  }
  
  return (
    <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '100%', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <div style={{overflowY: 'scroll', width: '100%'}}>
        {tasks.map(t => 
            <Task title={t.title} onChecked={() => completeTask(t)} additionalStyles={{backgroundColor: t.color}}/>
        )}
      </div>
      <Button variant='contained' fullWidth sx={{p: 1, m: 1}}>Add New</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### #1. key prop

The call to `tasks.map()` should be using unique `key` props on the `<Task>` component ([React Docs about keys](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key)).

### #2. incorrect use of filter()?

This line of code...

```
setTasks(tasks.filter(t => !t.isChecked));
```

...causes the Task containing the selected checkbox (let's say Task #1) to disappear (because the call to `.filter()` filters it out). When Task #1 disappears, the one below it (Task #2) takes its place and acts as if it were the task that was checked. This happens because React has no way of knowing that the first Task in the DOM (after Task #1 disappears) is actually Task #2, not Task #1. React can distinguish Task #1 from Task #2 when the **[key](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key)** prop is used.

Comment: Thank you! While you posted essentially the same answer as Berci, your explanation with the key makes more sense to me. Because there are no unique keys, if I am "checking" the 2nd item and the 2nd item is being removed, the new 2nd item is retaining the old 2nd item's state.

Comment: Hi @derekantrican. Glad it helped. Berci's answer addresses other important issues. But, I didn't go into those since I don't know what your intention is for the `completeTask()` function. Maybe you could post another question if you are having other problems with the `<App>` component.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm encountering a problem where checking an item also checks the one
> below it in the list:
>
> Any ideas what could be causing this?

Well that is not really what is happening. Your code behavior is triggered by:

1. You are directly trying to mutate a state when you do `task.isChecked = true;` which you should never do as mentioned [in react docs](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state).
2. You are not using any key on your array rendering. You can read more about why react needs keys [here](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys) (I would actually recommend the full article), but basically what is happening is that you trying to change an object that you hold in the React state and afterwards you remove that object from the list. However because you don't have any unique keys in your rendering, reacts 'thinks' that first element from your array is checked, and because your original first element is removed combined with the fact that you don't use keys triggers this behaviour.

---

What you should do instead:

1. You don't really need to set anything to checked. You can just have something like  `const completeTask = (task) =>  setTasks(tasks.filter(t => t.title !== task.title))`
2. Add a key to your JSX elements directly inside the map(), so something like

```
{tasks.map(t => 
  <Task key={t.title} title={t.title} onChecked={() => completeTask(t)} additionalStyles={{backgroundColor: t.color}}/>
)}
```

WARNING: while either one of this condition would work by itself (without the other one), I really recommend not skipping either of them, since by doing so you might cause other unexpected behaviour in the future

Comment: For the filter you could probably just get away with the reference comparison of the task instead of comparing the titles: `const completeTask = (task) =>  setTasks(tasks.filter(t => t !== task))`.